# Construct subquery in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent, subquery

I tried building eloquent subquery for the attached MySQL subquery. Can anyone help to construct the subquery?

```
select account_name 
from nn_account 
where account_parentid in ( select account_id 
                            from account 
                            where account_name = 'Club Fees' 
                              and account_tenant_id = 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use subquery. Use

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.account_name 
FROM nn_account t1
JOIN account t2 ON t1.account_parentid = t2.account_id 
WHERE t2.account_name = 'Club Fees' 
  AND t2.account_tenant_id = 1 ;
```

It can be easily built in Eloquent syntax.